# auto-populate a view from the UserProfile Table and the Billing table fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view

I will like to get the AddressAndPayment view being auto-populate from the UserProfile table.

I will like to use the fields from the UserProfile table to be auto-displayed in the AddressAndPayment.cshtml.  I can't figure out how to perform this.

Some fields needs to come from Billing.cs and some other from the UserProfile Table.

Thanks.

The view I wanted to be populate is

AddressAndPayment.cshtml

```
 @model Tp1WebStore3.Models.Billing

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "AddressAndPayment";
 }

 <h2>Billing Info</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

     <fieldset>
         <legend>Billing</legend>

         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.BillingId)

         <div class="editor-label">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastNameBilling)
         </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastNameBilling)
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastNameBilling)
         </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstNameBilling)
         </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstNameBilling)
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrenomFact)
         </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
             @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdressBilling)
         </div>

         <div class="editor-field">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdressBilling)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdressBilling)
        </div>
```

Here are the field I store in the UserProfileTable  from the AccountModels.cs

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Adress { get; set; }

}
```

Billing.cs

```
 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Models
 {
     [Bind(Exclude = "BillingId")]


     public partial class Billing
     {
         [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
         public int BillingId { get; set; }

         [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
         public System.DateTime DateBilling { get; set; }

         public string LastNameBilling { get; set; }

         public string FirstNameBilling { get; set; }

         public string AdresseBilling { get; set; }
```

CheckoutController.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using Tp1WebStore3.Models;

 namespace Tp1WebStore3.Controllers
 {
     [Authorize]
     public class CheckoutController : Controller
     {

         Tp1WebStoreDBEntities storeDB = new Tp1WebStoreDBEntities();

         //
         // GET: /Checkout/AddressAndPayment 

         public ActionResult AddressAndPayment()
         {
             return View();
         }

         //
         // POST: /Checkout/AddressAndPayment
         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(FormCollection values)
         {
             var billing = new Billing();
             TryUpdateModel(billing);

             try
             {
                    billing.DateBilling = DateTime.Now; 

                     //Process the order
                     var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);

                     cart.CreateOrder(billing);

                     return RedirectToAction("Complete",
                         new { id = billing.BillingId });

             }
             catch
             {
                 //Invalid - redisplay with errors
                 return View(billing);
             }
         }

         //
         // GET: /Checkout/Complete
         public ActionResult Complete(int id)
         {
             return View(id);

         }

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your `AddressAndPayment` `GET` action method:

```
//GET: /Checkout/AddressAndPayment 
public ActionResult AddressAndPayment(int userId)
{
   var user = storeDB.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == Id);
   var billing = new Billing();
   billing.AdresseBilling = user.Adresse;
   //etc... add anything else you need here
   return View(billing);
}
```

Since it seems you are requiring that the user be logged in to get this far, then you could get the `id` from the current logged in user.

Comment: UserProfiles is not in the StoreDB.  When I added the UserProfile it was put in the DefaultConnection db (it was store in a different DB. Now I got 2 DB 1 for login and one with all the other tables for my project).  Any idea on how to get the UserProfile table?

Comment: Well basically the idea is still the same just query the other database for the user information necessary and then populate the billing object with the information from it and return it to your `View`. Can't be any more specific without knowing about the other database.